# Jmeter: Upload a zip to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, jmeter, upload, performance-testing

I need to upload a zip filr on Amazon S3 bucket from Presigned URL which contains AWSAccessKeyId, Expires and Signature details and in HTTP Headers Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed.

I am trying to upload HTTP Request, the file to be uploaded is kept at jmeter bin folder. During execution, Content-Type value is getting changed and i am getting "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error: in jMeter

[image]

To upload a zip file to Amazon S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be using:

- [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/)
- [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

AWS provides [example code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object) you can use for uploading your file:

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;

System.out.format("Uploading %s to S3 bucket %s...\n", file_path, bucket_name);
final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build();
try {
    s3.putObject(bucket_name, key_name, new File(file_path));
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
```

If you want to continue using the HTTP Request sampler the URL is not something you should "sign", it should look like `https://your-bucket.your-region.amazonaws.com/your-file-name.zip`

And AWS access key and signature should be a part of the [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header in form of:

```
Authorization: AWS your-secret-key:signature
```

Comment: can we disable  HTTPHC4Impl to not replace Content-Header

INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: Content-Header is set already on the request! Will be replaced by a Multipart-Header. Old headers: [Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed]

Comment: Untick `Use multipart/form-data` box

Comment: After untick Use multipart/form-data box, still Content-Header is getting replaced

Comment: Replaced to what? Have you added a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and configured it to send the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header you want to send?

Comment: yes, I have configured HTTP Header as 'Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed' but at run time it changes to 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={value}';

Comment: It shouldn't be the case, the only thing I can think of is that you have [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) somewhere and `Use multipart-form/data` box is checked there. You can also [enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) and see what causes the header override in [meter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file